# How do I determine my GHC version?

Tags: haskell, version, ghc

This is probably a very dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer...

Comment: Have you tried `ghc --version` in the command line?

Comment: You might have multiple! A hacky but very easy way to check which ones is to type `ghc-` into your terminal, then hit tab to ask your shell for completions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ghc --version` did the trick on Ubuntu, thanks Karolis!

Edit: works on mac too (macOS Sierra 10.12.6)

Answer (score 45):

To find which version my `stack` is using, I ran

```
$ stack ghc -- --version
```

and got

```
$ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2
```

Comment: Nice use of the double hyphen!
Can be used with the sandboxed version of ghc as well!

Comment: Warning: if you do not have `ghc` installed, this command will download almost 200MB and install `ghc` in your system.

Comment: @evaristegd Just happened to me: `Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.`

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your [install method](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/#platform) and architecture, some commands may differ. Some people may have several versions installed. Here is a selection of information that may be useful:

***stack version***

```sh
❯ stack --version
Version 2.1.3, Git revision 0fa51b9925decd937e4a993ad90cb686f88fa282 (7739 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.2
```

***ghc version (as noted by [@mherzl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3224967/mherzl))***

```sh
❯ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
```

***standard ghc version command***

```sh
❯ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.1
```

***cabal version***

```sh
❯ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.0.0.0
compiled using version 3.0.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

***GHC's repl***

```sh
❯ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.1
```

***If using llvm with `-fllvm` flag***

```sh
❯ llvm-gcc -v
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```