# Can I find the GHC version from inside GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

```
λ>
```

What do I type within `GHCi` to discover which GHC version it is using?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073792/how-do-i-determine-my-ghc-version). I realize that question doesn't answer yours, but someone who finds this question later may find that one useful.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that `:version` isn't a command.

Comment: @chepner I agree, but note that on startup GHCi prints its version: `GHCi, version 8.10.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help`.

Comment: When I open `GHCi` in `emacs`' `haskell-mode`, I am greeted with `The lambdas must flow.`. No mention of its version.

Answer (score 13):

```
> import System.Info
> :browse
arch :: String
compilerName :: String
compilerVersion :: Data.Version.Version
os :: String
> compilerVersion
Version {versionBranch = [8,10], versionTags = []}
> compilerName
"ghc"
```

On top of that, GHCi prints its version on startup:

```
GHCi, version 8.10.3: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```